# Unable to change bitrate on wifi adapter

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I'm having issues with my Belkin N-300 USB wifi adapter. I can connect fine, but about a week ago the connection started getting very slow and regularly drops. Bringing the interface down and back up sometimes work and rebooting usually does. I've tried upgrading the kernel, but to no effect.

My signal quality is not that good, so I'm thinking part of the problem might be corruption caused by my high bitrate.
According to `iwlist`, the current bitrate is not supported:

```
wlp2s0u2  4 available bit-rates :
          1 Mb/s
          2 Mb/s
          5.5 Mb/s
          11 Mb/s

          Current Bit Rate:150 Mb/s
```

I've tried changing it using `iwconfig`, specifically:

`sudo iwconfig wlp2s0u2 rate 11M`

which exits without error but does not actually change the bitrate. I've also tried with `iw`:

`sudo iw dev wlp2s0u2 set bitrates legacy-2.4 11`

but this returns the error `command failed: No such device (-19)`, and similarly any `iw` command referencing wlp2s0u2 fails.

Relevant output of `iwconfig`:

```
wlp2s0u2  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:redacted  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 5C:96:9D:65:40:A3   
          Bit Rate:150 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=99/100  Signal level=61/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I'm running Arch Linux with kernel 3.14.1-1.

Comment: This is a realtek rebranding USB. Bugs...

Answer (score 0):

This is a *bit* late, but as far as I understand, you need to turn wifi off before doing it, and on again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The commands used to increase your WiFi adapter's reach are:

```
iw reg set US

iwconfig wlp2s0u2 txpower 30
```

`reg set` sets the country code to US, which has a higher max throughput (30 dBm).

`txpower` sets the dBm power level.

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw#setting_tx_power