# Unable to change default bitrate of wireless network interface

Tags: linux, wifi, network-interface

I am trying to change the bitrate of my wireless nic (AR9565 driver: ath9k_htc) for experimentation purposes. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my card details are as follows:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"FACULTY-STAFF-N"  
             Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: C4:0A:CB:2D:75:5A   
             Bit Rate=240 Mb/s   Tx-Power=17 dBm   
             Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
             Power Management:off
             Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
             Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
             Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

To fix the bitrate (9Mbps in this case, but I checked multiple bit rates), I use these commands:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 set bitrates legacy-5 9
```

OR

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 9M
```

I check the maximum bit rate used by wlan0 by `iw dev wlan0 link`; `iwconfig wlan0` and I check the current bitrate used by interface through `glances`. However, none of these commands seem to have any effect on the bit rate.

This is the information on running `iw dev wlan0 link`:

```
Connected to c4:0a:cb:2d:75:55 (on wlan0)
SSID: FACULTY-STAFF-N
freq: 2462
RX: 420678 bytes (1949 packets)
TX: 144065 bytes (850 packets)
signal: -57 dBm
tx bitrate: 130.0 MBit/s MCS 14 short GI

bss flags:  short-preamble short-slot-time
dtim period:    1
beacon int: 102
```

The accepted answer to the related question asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126707/unable-to-change-bitrate-on-wifi-adapter) requires me to bring down the interface before I change the rates. However, doing so I encounter the following error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Bit Rate" (8B20) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Network is down
```

Also I tried iw list. This command does not return all available rates but returns the current rate.

Comment: My wireless chipset is AR9565 (driver: ath9k_htc). I checked for multiple bit rates. Also I tried iw list. This command does not return all available rates but returns the current rate.

Comment: I have also used different laptops, another one using Atheros AR9485.

Comment: did you check the available bit rates on the AP side too?. Do they include the bit-rates you tried?. For future reference: Add new information (like "I tried another device, AR9485") to the Question, not into comments. If the new information is in response to a commenter asking for it, perhaps flag it as helpful, and then -after adding the new info- flag the comment asking for it as "obsolete". That way the comment section can be kept on-topic, up2date and "clean".

Comment: I'm having weird behavior as well. If I use `iwconfig`, then the rate will be set to either 1 or 11 and I cannot get it back to anything faster without resetting the adapter. If I use `iw`, any changes seem to affect only `tx`. Rx keeps switching wildly across modulations, free like the wind.

Answer (score 1):

I will be assuming that the WiFi card is called wlan0. I will divide the answer in two parts:

1. ***Fixing the Error***

Run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` to start the network, because you are getting error : `SET failed on device wlan0 ; Network is down`

2. ***How to change the bitrate properly***

Run `iwlist wlan0 bitrate` first to check what bit rates are supported and  the current bitrate is.

Then, `iwconfig wlan0 bitrate 24M`